# How to avoid the child QMainWindow disappearing?

Tags: pyqt, exec, qmainwindow

When I click the button, "ChildWindow" will flash and disappear. Then If I add the function exec_(), it will report an "AttributeError" because "QMainWindow" don't have this attribute. 
How to modify the function "showChildWindow" so that it can work well? Thank you.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("MainWindow Window!")
        self.setGeometry(400, 400, 100, 100) 
        self.centerWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centerWidget)

        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton("&Button")
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.centerWidget.setLayout(layout)    

class ChildWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Child Window!")

def showChildWindow():
    mw = MainWindow()
    child_win = ChildWindow(mw)
    child_win.show() 
    #child_win.exec_()                     #AttributeError: 'ChildWindow' object has no attribute 'exec_'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MainWindow()
    myapp.show()
    QtCore.QObject.connect(myapp.pushButton,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),showChildWindow)  
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This program can work well.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("MainWindow Window!")
        self.setGeometry(400, 400, 100, 100) 
        self.centerWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centerWidget)

        pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton("&Button")
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(pushButton)
        self.centerWidget.setLayout(layout)

        QtCore.QObject.connect(pushButton,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.showChildWindow)      

    def showChildWindow(self):
        self.child_win = ChildWindow(self)
        self.child_win.show()


class ChildWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Child Window!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MainWindow()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You've already answered your own question with the second example, so what's the problem?

Comment: For the first example, how to change the global functon "showChildWindow" so that it won't report error?  Thank you. I want to get the different way to write it.

Comment: As I said in my other comment, the second example solves the problem. It keeps a reference to the child window, whereas the first example allows the main-window (and all its children) to be garbage-collected immediately after it's shown. So why don't you want to use the example that works?

Comment: It is just a demo of my project. I need to open the child window in another file for using the Gui file. The functon "showChildWindow" must be a global functon instead of a method of one class. But the child window will flush and disapper soon.  I want it stays open until I close it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The real question appears to be: how do I access the main-window from other modules in my application?

My preferred general solution to this problem is to sub-class QApplication and add a simple accessor method, like this:

```
class Application(QtGui.QApplication):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QApplication.__init__(self, sys.argv)
        self._window = None

    def window(self):
        if self._window is None:
            self._window = MainWindow()
        return self._window

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtGui.qApp = Application()
    app.window().show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

With that in place, you can easily get access the methods of the main-window in other modules like this:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

QtGui.qApp.window().showChildWindow()
```

Comment: I solve it as below. Thank you all the same.


    def showChildWindow(self):
        child_win = ChildWindow(self)
        child_win.show()
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":    
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        myapp = MainWindow() 
        myapp.show()
        QtCore.QObject.connect(myapp.pushButton,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),lambda:showChildWindow(myapp))  
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  The child QMainWindow would randomly disappear while interacting with the parent window.

This is the bad source code that causes this problem:

```
def showChildWindow(self): 
    child_win = ChildWindow() 
    child_win.show()
```

This is the good source code that fixes the problem:

```
def showChildWindow(self): 
    child_win = ChildWindow(self) 
    child_win.show()
```

When you instantiate the child window, make sure you pass the parent self.